# Timezone hour in sudo crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I did the following cron task with `sudo crontab -e`:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/docker_build/backup.sh
```

Cron works well (launch backup to each hour).
In this bash script, I write a backup sql file based on this pattern :

```
DATE_NOW=$(date +%Y-%d-%m-%H-%M)
$DATE_NOW.sql
```

But the hour return by %H variable is not the hour of my current timezone.

I check the following commmand in my shell :

```
date //return good date

cat /etc/timezone //return good timezone
```

**UPDATE :**

It was a very stupid mistake. To be short, my bash script run in a docker container. The container timezone wasn't set with my current timezone. I had the following in my image build :

```
RUN echo America/Montreal > /etc/timezone && \
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: And in the shell of the user that crontab runs as?

Comment: What do you mean ? I only set this task in sudo crontab.

Comment: Edit the question with my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the timezone in the crontab entry

```
0 * * * * env TZ='Europe/Madrid' /usr/local/bin/docker_build/backup.sh
```

Or, I suppose, in the crontab itself

```
TZ='Europe/Madrid'
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/docker_build/backup.sh
```

You can find out what the timezone is in root's cron environment

```
* * * * * date "+\%F \%T \%Z \%z" > /tmp/root.cron.date.txt
```

Comment: I'll try with your two first answers. Hour is still wrong. I did a try with the third one and it's correct.